# Callback after all functions done

Tags: javascript, callback, event-loop

This is just such a task, challenge, literally, everything that I have outlined is all information

We can add another argument for callback 'all is done'.

Important, console.log('all is done') need to be displayed only after all 
'timer' functions have completed their execution, regardless of their call order.

I can’t figure out which way to approach the task, I need to output using callback, but I need to wait for all calls to be completed
What we have:

```js
//Write a “timer” function which takes a function and timeout, after all executions fire a callback (‘all is done’):

const timer = // your code


timer( () => {
 console.log(500)
}, 500 )

timer( () => {
 console.log(3000)
}, 3000 )

timer( () => {
 console.log(1500)
}, 1500 )

timer( () => {
 console.log(2500)
}, 2500 )
```

Comment: What does “after all executions” mean? Who defines how often and with what actual “delays” this gets called?

Comment: Sounds like you should ask your teacher for clarification. If a function takes a single function and timeout, "all executions" is "the execution" and is the single function the callback or what gets executed?

Comment: Is this for an assignment or a specific problem you need to solve? Either way you should clarify the assignment/problem a bit more

Comment: OP is probably supposed to learn about generators and yield.

Comment: @04FS I mean after all function calls "timer".
in this case, it does not matter who determines what the delay will be (ms), let it be as in the example, I myself set the delay in milliseconds, but the order of the function call can be different.

Comment: @HereticMonkey we can add another argument for callback 'all is done'

Comment: Keep a global counter variable that you increase by one on each `timer` call, and decrease it inside the callback …? When it reaches 0 again in the latter, you know you’re done with “everything”.

Comment: @Loxx This is just such a task, challenge, literally everything that I have outlined is all information

Comment: @04FS this is an interesting thought

Answer (score 0):

If it is a promise related question, your constance returns a function with promise:

```
const timer = (timeout) =>  {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(timeout) {
    resolve(() => { console.log(timeout)});
  }, timeout);
});
}

Promise.all().then( () => { alert("All is done") })
```

Comment: "constance"? That's a name, not a word (in English).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.
It would be cool to solve it without using a global variable.

```js
//Write a “timer” function which takes a function and timeout, after all executions fire a callback (‘all is done’):
let maxTimer = 0;
const timer = async (toRun, timeout) => {
  ++maxTimer
  const done = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      toRun()
      resolve()
    }, timeout)
  } )

  if (maxTimer === 0){
    console.log('all is done')
  }
}// your code


timer( () => {
  console.log(6000)
  --maxTimer
}, 6000 )

timer( () => {
  console.log(500)
  --maxTimer
}, 500 )

timer( () => {
  console.log(1500)
  --maxTimer
}, 1500 )

timer( () => {
  console.log(7000)
  --maxTimer
}, 7000 )

timer( () => {
  console.log(2500)
  --maxTimer
}, 2500 )
```